# How to get value from other when using ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to get value from other when using ajax post ?

i want to get value from input `type="text" class="nextpage"` in demo.php
to input `<input type='hidden' id='page_number' name='page' value='1'/>` in index.php

i try to do like this code but not work , How can i do that ?

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>





<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ // onload page for load content //    
        document.getElementById('page_number').value = '1'; 
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'demo.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#xxx1').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#results").append(data); 
                    function_two();
                }
            }
         )
  });
</script>

    <form method="post" id="xxx1" action="Javascript:void(0);">
        <input type='hidden' id='page_number' name='page' value='1'/>
    </form>



<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ // click button for load content //
      $("#Button").click(function(e){    
        var page = $('#results').find('.nextpage').val();
        document.getElementById('page_number').value = page++; 
        $.ajax
        (
            {
                url: 'demo.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#xxx2').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#results").append(data); 
                    function_two();
                }
            }
         )
  });
});
</script>

    <form method="post" id="xxx2" action="Javascript:void(0);">
        <input type='hidden' id='page_number' name='page' value='1'/>
    </form>



<div id="results" style=" width: 100%; "></div>
<input type="submit" id="Button" value="OK">
```

demo.php

```
<?PHP
$page = $_POST[page];
$nextpage = ($page+1);
?>
<input type='text' class='nextpage' value='<?PHP echo $nextpage; ?>'>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes for `$page = $_POST[page];` - `$page = $_POST['page'];`? Plus, `<input type="submit" id="Button" value="OK">` is outside your form tags.

Comment: @  Fred -ii- not work ....

Comment: Seems to have worked for me. What I get is the number `2` inside a textbox, when I click `OK` I get another textbox appearing, and another if I keep clicking. Is that the expected result you wish to get?

Comment: and then click button again value number not `3`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean that if I click again the number should be `3`?

Comment: yes, When load page `<input type="hidden" class="nextpage" value="2">`

and when click button `<input type="hidden" class="nextpage" value="3">` and when click button again `<input type="hidden" class="nextpage" value="4">`......

Answer (score 0):

OK, i get answer , cause of issue from duplicate id name `page_number`

just change

`document.getElementById('page_number').value = '1';`

to

`document.getElementById('page_number_1').value = '1';`

and change

```
<form method="post" id="xxx1" action="Javascript:void(0);">
    <input type='hidden' id='page_number' name='page' value='1'/>
</form>
```

to

```
<form method="post" id="xxx1" action="Javascript:void(0);">
    <input type='hidden' id='page_number_1' name='page' value='1'/>
</form>
```

it's will work.......

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code little bit. Instead returning entire HTML input from the PHP page, I just return the page number and append the input from the front end using jquery.
Hope this will work for you

```
**index.php**
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ // onload page for load content //    
            document.getElementById('page_number').value = '1'; 
            $.ajax
            (
                {
                    url: 'demo.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#xxx1').serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#results").append("<input type='text' class='nextpage' value='"+data.page_number+"'>"); 
                        function_two();
                    }
                }
            )
        });
    </script>

    <form method="post" id="xxx1" action="Javascript:void(0);">
        <input type='hidden' id='page_number' name='page' value='1'/>
    </form> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ // click button for load content //
            $("#Button").click(function(e){    
                var page = $('#results').find('.nextpage').val();
                document.getElementById('page_number').value = page++; 
                $.ajax
                (
                    {
                        url: 'demo.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $('#xxx2').serialize(),
                        dataType:'json',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#results").append("<input type='text' class='nextpage' value='"+data.page_number+"'>"); 
                            function_two();
                        }
                    }
                )
            });
        });
    </script>

    <form method="post" id="xxx2" action="Javascript:void(0);">
        <input type='hidden' id='page_number' name='page' value='1'/>
    </form>

    <div id="results" style=" width: 100%; "></div>
    <input type="submit" id="Button" value="OK">


**demo.php**

<?PHP
    $page = $_POST[page];
    $nextpage = ($page+1);
    if($nextpage){
        echo json_encode(array("page_number" => $nextpage));
    }
?>
```

Comment: check the demo.php. I have just returned the page number only from there.(Usually json_encode is used for that).
And then in your index.php , inside the script get the data.page_number and append the input to the required HTML element(#results)